# how to change title color in python pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
prs=Presentation()
title_slide_layout=prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide=prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
background=slide.background
fill = background.fill
fill.solid()
fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(59, 89, 152)
title=slide.shapes.title
subtitle=slide.placeholders[1]
title.text="title"
subtitle.text="Subtitle"
prs.save('mynewone.pptx')
```

i tired to change the same i changed the backgroud but i dint work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to handle the shape's `text_frame` property and apply that font formatting to the `paragraphs`. I think this should work, according to the [documentation](http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html):

```
title.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(59,89, 152)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'SlidePlaceholder' object has no attribute 'font'

Comment: revised answer & link to dox.

Comment: t means title ?

Comment: yeah sorry I was copying from console

Comment: but really, the colors should be mostly if not 100% defined by your layout. if you're constantly changing the defaults, just create a new layout manually which conforms to your requirements.